# Excel vba class in a dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, class, dictionary

I'm adding class items to a dictionary but i'm unable to get them back. Do i need to loop or what am I doing wrong?

My class module "cOgg" has:

```
Public desc As String
Public alt As Single
```

and my sub has:

```
sub pivo()
Dim oMat As New cOgg
Dim sosdb As New Dictionary
Set sosdb = Nothing

oMat.desc= "unodesc"
oMat.alt= 5
sosdb.Add "uno", oMat

oMat.desc= "duedesc"
oMat.alt= 10
sosdb.Add "due", oMat
Debug.Print (sosdb("uno").alt)
Debug.Print (sosdb("due").alt)
end sub
```

If i run the sub, i get :

```
10
10
```

instead of

```
5
10
```

Any ideas?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must set your `oMat` variable to a new instance of the `cOgg` class after adding it so you have two instances of the class object in your dictionary.

```
sub pivo()
    Dim oMat As New cOgg
    Dim sosdb As New Dictionary
    Set sosdb = Nothing

    oMat.desc= "unodesc"
    oMat.alt= 5
    sosdb.Add "uno", oMat

    Set oMat = New cOgg
    oMat.desc= "duedesc"
    oMat.alt= 10
    sosdb.Add "due", oMat
    Debug.Print (sosdb("uno").alt)
    Debug.Print (sosdb("due").alt)
end sub
```

If you don't do this then the `oMat` in the `"Uno"` entry is getting updated after it's being added to be 10. Then you add the same exact instance of `cOgg` held in `oMat` to the `"due"` entry of the dictionary. So both `"uno"` and `"due"` hold the same instance of the object, which are identical and have an `alt` of `10`

Comment: Once you get the solution, it's always like... oh, it was so easy! But i lost few hours trying (and failing) to figure this "easy" thing out! thanks a lot

Comment: No worries. Totally been there!